# Zap scan post methods using automation framework requestor

Tags: zap

Below is my test plan to scan a post api, but the result is always empty, what i am doing wrong?

```
  env:
  contexts:
  - name: "Default Context"
    urls:
    - "http://9.30.215.23:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
    includePaths:
    - "http://9.30.215.23:3100/loki/api/v1/push.*"
    excludePaths:
    - "http://localhost:9093/"
    authentication:
      parameters: {}
      verification:
        method: "response"
        pollFrequency: 60
        pollUnits: "requests"
    sessionManagement:
      method: "cookie"
      parameters: {}
    technology:
      exclude: []
  parameters:
    failOnError: true
    failOnWarning: false
    progressToStdout: true
  vars: {}
jobs:
- parameters:
    user: ""
  requests:
  - url: "http://9.30.215.23:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
    name: "Push"
    method: "POST"
    httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"
    headers:
    - "Content-Type:application/json"
    data: "{\"streams\": [{ \"stream\": { \"foo\": \"bar2\" }, \"values\": [ [ \"1674533290000000000\", \"fizzbuzz\" ] ] }]}"
    responseCode: 204
  name: "POST"
  type: "requestor"
- parameters:
    context: "Default Context"
    user: ""
    policy: ""
    maxRuleDurationInMins: 0
    maxScanDurationInMins: 0
  policyDefinition:
    defaultStrength: "medium"
    defaultThreshold: "off"
    rules:
    - id: 40012
      name: "Cross Site Scripting (Reflected)"
      threshold: "medium"
      strength: "default"
  name: "activeScan"
  type: "activeScan"
- parameters:
    template: "traditional-pdf"
    reportDir: "/Users/jijesh"
    reportFile: ""
    reportTitle: "ZAP Scanning Report"
    reportDescription: ""
    displayReport: true
  risks:
  - "info"
  - "low"
  - "medium"
  - "high"
  confidences:
  - "falsepositive"
  - "low"
  - "medium"
  - "high"
  - "confirmed"
  sections:
  - "instancecount"
  - "alertdetails"
  - "alertcount"
  name: "report"
  type: "report"
```

Comment: Do you mean the report is completely empty (ie blank) or has things in it but no alerts, or the repult of the POST request is blank?? More details please!

Comment: Yes, the report has things but no alerts.

Comment: Are you expecting any? The URL you have added is http://9.30.215.23:3100/loki/api/v1/push - that looks like an API. If its a API then its likely to be serving up JSON or similar structured data. That will not be vulnerable to XSS - only HTML pages are typically vulnerable to XSSs.